# Clearing subscriptions: What will break this self-cleaning event publisher?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, delegates, event-handling

I've been studying garbage collection and event handlers, and in my studies, I came across some code that appears to clean all subscriptions, anonymous or otherwise, from an event handler. The code is as follows:

```
public event CustomEventHandler customHandler;

...    
///Something somewhere subscribes to the customHandler
...

///Method used for cleanup
void ClearSubscriptions(CustomEventHandler handler){
     if(handler == null){return;}

     Delegate[] delegates = handler.GetInvocationList();
     foreach(Delegate item in delegates){
         handler -= (CustomEventHandler)item;
     }
}

...

///And in the Dispose method
ClearSubscriptions(customHandler);
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find the original answer that had this code, so I can't properly give credit (feel free to edit if anyone knows where to find it).

Now, my understanding of this is that it seems to take the event handler and remove all subscriptions to it, anonymous or otherwise, freeing it up for garbage collection. Particularly, putting this code in a Dispose method seems like a failsafe way to make sure that this handler will not cause a memory leak.

So my question is, assuming that the Dispose method will call this ClearSubscriptions method, what situations will break the ClearSubscriptions method and cause it to work in a way other than what I expect?

Comment: This actually won't clear the event subscriptions because delegates are immutable. You are passing the value of a field into ClearSubscriptions but then only updating a local variable. However there is a simple way to clear subscriptions to an event, set it to null.

Comment: If you're just concerned about a memory leak, it seems overkill (assuming your disposable object with this event will otherwise be eligible for collection). Once the event owning object is eligible for collection, its event wont keep other objects alive.

Comment: Or to put it another way - if you're concerned about memory leaks, actually profile/dump your code and work out how they're happening rather than cargo-culting your code.

Comment: The usual concern re: memory leaks and event handlers is that a long-lived object has subscribers that are meant to be short-lived (and badly written because they fail to unsubscribe themselves). But if you're only running `ClearSubscriptions` when the long-lived object is meant to disappear anyway, you're not addressing *that* concern.

Comment: Hmm... so it sounds like this has no advantages to just setting the handler to null, and merely ends up wasting computer cycles instead. Is that correct?

Comment: It depends, maybe you want to guarantee that events will not be raised after the object is disposed. Clearing any event handlers is good way to do that. However this has nothing to do with memory usage or leaks really.