# Can an event's publisher unsubscribe its listeners?

Tags: c#, .net, events, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

In [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52745233/clearing-subscriptions-what-will-break-this-self-cleaning-event-publisher), I asked what would break a self-cleaning block of code designed to remove all subscriptions from an event's delegates field when the event's parent object is disposed. However, I was informed that setting the event to null does exactly what I was trying to do with the code in question, but without the extra cycles and lines of code.

[This article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43987/Event-Handling-and-Garbage-Collection-in-NET) demonstrates that setting an event to null (clearing the delegate field) does not guarantee that nothing is listening for it, and that even if the event is set to null, it may still be kept from the garbage collector.

So the question is, is there a way for the publisher to unsubscribe its listeners?

--

For context, I am aware that the listener is normally expected to remove its own subscription when it is done listening, but I would like a little bit more certainty than that, if possible. Also, I occasionally have to deal with code where I'm not entirely sure if all listeners have unsubscribed when the publisher is disposed.

In case it's relevant, the code from my last question is as follows:

```
    public event CustomEventHandler customHandler;

    ...    
    ///During this object's lifetime, some other object subscribes to this event.
    ...

    ///Method used for cleanup
    void ClearSubscriptions(CustomEventHandler handler){
         if(handler == null){return;}

         Delegate[] delegates = handler.GetInvocationList();
         foreach(Delegate item in delegates){
             handler -= (CustomEventHandler)item;
         }
    }
```

This clears the event's delegates list, but I've been told that just setting customHandler = null should do the same. I also thought that this would ensure that nothing was still listening/referencing the event, but that does not seem to be the case, as is explained below.

To summarize the relevant code in the referenced article, the article's example is a form that allows the user to generate an "EventGenerator" object under one of three different conditions:

1.) There is no cleanup on the object's events.

2.) The publisher cleans up by setting the event to null.

3.) The listener cleans up by unsubscribing from the event.

These are controlled by a radio check, so only one condition may be active at a time. The EventGenerator object has an event that is fired when it is created. Each EventGenerator is assigned a number, starting at 0 and incrementing. The form has an event handler that subscribes to this event, and whenever that event is fired, the event handler prints that a new EventGenerator has been created, along with that object's number. Additionally, the form only references one EventGenerator at a time, so whenever a new one is created, the previous one is forgotten.

Under option 1, every time a new one of these objects is created, all objects that have been created fire off an "I've been created" dialog. This is expected since the form is still subscribed to all of these instances, even if they have been dereferenced.

Under option 3, when a new object is created, the form unsubscribes from the previous EventGenerator's event before dereferencing it, so the new object's "created" dialog displays, as well as the old object's "finalized" dialog. This demonstrates that the object has been gathered by the garbage collector and no longer holds any resources.

Option 2 is what confuses me. When option 2 is active, if a new EventGenerator is created, then the old one is disposed. The form does not unsubscribe, but the previous object does set its event to null. The "New Object" dialog is displayed once, with the new object's number. The previous generators are silent, meaning their events aren't being fired, and that is good. However, their "finalized" dialog never fires. This means that, even though the event has been set to null, the EventGenerator is still not eligible for garbage collection, creating a memory leak.

It seems to me that this is probably because the form itself never unsubscribes from the event under option 2. Then, even though the event doesn't really exist anymore, the form is still pointing at it, and that keeps the garbage collector away.

So with that context, I am curious. Is there a way for an event's publisher to unsubscribe its listeners and let Option 2 free up those dereferenced objects?

Also, sorry for this extra information being so verbose!

Comment: The only way for there to be a difference between unsubscribing each handler individually and just setting the whole thing to null is if there is a custom add/remove method for the event that does something other than just changing a backing delegate when removing (which, for the record, seems like a bad idea).  Since you don't have custom add/remove handlers in your example, you cannot be in that position.